# How to expand a filename inside a curl request

Tags: bash, curl

I need to do a curl upload with a file where I don't know the exact file name.

```
"curl
-F \"status=2\"
-F \"notify=1\"
-F \"ipa=@${FILE}\"
-F \"teams=${TEAM_ID}\"
-H \"X-HockeyAppToken: ${APITOKEN}\"
https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/${APPVERSION}/app_versions/upload"
```

This is done in gitlab-ci and the `FILE` variable is set to `build/com.test.app_v*.ipa`. The file I want to upload has a version number set and has the path `build/com.test.app_v1.0.0.0.ipa`. The problem I have now is that the `*` does not get expanded inside this curl call. I've tried it with an export before:

```
- export ABSOLUTE_FILENAME=${FILE}
- "curl
  -F \"status=2\"
  -F \"notify=1\"
  -F \"ipa=@${ABSOLUTE_FILENAME}\"
  -F \"teams=${TEAM_ID}\"
  -H \"X-HockeyAppToken: ${APITOKEN}\"
  https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/${APPVERSION}/app_versions/upload"
```

Still I'm gettin an error `curl: (26) couldn't open file "build/com.test.app_v*.ipa"` How can I expand the path to an absolute path before my curl upload?

Comment: Double quotes prevent globbing. Remove the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `realpath` command:

```
...
-F \"ipa=@$(realpath $FILE)\"
...
```